# How to Push Dynamic table from 1 div to another and how to get the values of it after pressing Save

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Hi i am new to angular here i have a requirement i have a dynamic data by using that i am filling the drop down and after selecting the dropdown value the table has to been generated dynamically including dynamica check boxes up this i can generate but the problem i am facing is

1. How to push table from table1 div to table2 div and if i make any changes in table 2 and press save i have to save the changes which i made in table 2 value 
   [image]

Comment: Is any effort form your side ? If yes , post your code for better solution.